# A barred crossword

Tags: crosswords

[image]

#### Across

**1** Powers
**5** Cops in much of Europe
**8** Online rule
**9** Body named for a national park
**10** Studio
**11** Vigevano
**14** 1940 song, sort of
**15** Triangle
**16** Partner killer
**17** Value of a question
**19** A strike
**20** Tanakh program
**21** A lot is over this

#### Down

**1** Odds
**2** Call Chidi
**3** A cube's square
**4** 1982 hit
**5** NIN song
**6** 1919 play
**7** Dr. Pepper's
**12** Depth
**13** 2008 show
**17** A position
**18** Answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The trick to the puzzle:

> The grid should be filled with *numbers*, not letters.

The solved grid, with clues explained:

> [image]

[Thanks to El-Guest, trolley813, and Darrel Hoffman for helping me finish off the explanations.]

Comment: I thought it was!!! But I kept convincing myself I was wrong because of various clues lol +1

Comment: 2 Down is rot13(gbhpu-gbar cubar) translation — that is, rot13(2 ba n xrlcnq vf NOP, 3 vf QRS, etc.)

Comment: Great! All your answers so far are correct; +1. @El-Guest, you're right, too, though the association you mention predates rot13(gbhpu-gbar).

Comment: And 9 across is rot13(ahzore bs na nfgrebvq anzrq nsgre gur angvbany cnex bs Priraarf)

Comment: @msh210 I was trying to figure out a good way to explain it without being explicit, then found I couldn’t haha and needed the example

Comment: I think 19 across is rot13(n onfronyy ersrerapr: mreb onyyf, bar fgevxr).